# How to accelerate batch-size data from memory when using dataloader

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, dataloader

I am trying to use dataloader for training. The dataset is 150G, which are all .npz files. Due to the limitation of memory size, only one sample is read at a time from the disk. The following is part of the code.

```
class VimeoDataset(Dataset):
def __init__(self, mode, batch_size=32, num_workers = 8, num_gpus = 4):
    self.batch_size = batch_size
    self.num_workers = num_workers
    self.num_gpus = num_gpus
    self.mode = mode
    self.load_data()
    self.h = 256
    self.w = 448
    xx = np.arange(0, self.w).reshape(1,-1).repeat(self.h,0)
    yy = np.arange(0, self.h).reshape(-1,1).repeat(self.w,1)
    self.grid = np.stack((xx,yy),2).copy()
    self.npzs=[]

    count = self.batch_size * self.num_workers * self.num_gpus
    if self.mode == 'train':
        filelist = glob('/data/vimeoFlow2/dataset/train/*.npz')
        self.npzs = [filelist[i:i + count] for i in range(0, len(filelist), count)]
    else:
        filelist = glob('/data/vimeoFlow2/dataset/val/*.npz')
        self.npzs = [filelist[i:i + count] for i in range(0, len(filelist), count)]

def __len__(self):
    return len(self.npzs)

def load_data(self, index):
    self.data = []
    self.flow_data = []

    for i in range(len(self.npzs[index])):
        f = np.load(self.npzs[index][i])
        self.data.append(f['i0i1gt'])
        if self.mode == 'train':
            self.flow_data.append(f['ft0ft1'])
        else:
            self.flow_data.append(np.zeros((256, 448, 4)))    

def getimg(self, index):
    data = self.meta_data[index]
    img0 = data[0:3].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    img1 = data[3:6].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    gt = data[6:9].transpose(1, 2, 0)
    flow_gt = (self.flow_data[index]).transpose(1, 2, 0)
    return img0, gt, img1, flow_gt
        
def __getitem__(self, index):        
    img0, gt, img1, flow_gt = self.getimg(index)

dataset = VimeoDataset(mode = 'train',  batch_size=32, num_workers = 8, num_gpus = 4)
sampler = DistributedSampler(dataset)
train_data = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=args.batch_size, pin_memory=True, num_workers=args.num_workers, drop_last=True, sampler=sampler)
dataset_val = VimeoDataset(mode = 'val',  batch_size=32, num_workers = 8, num_gpus = 4)
val_data = DataLoader(dataset_val, batch_size=args.batch_size, pin_memory=True, num_workers=args.num_workers)
```

However, reading data from the disk one by one causes the dataloader to be very time-consuming. So I want to improve this program, first load the amount of data of `num_gpus×num_workers×batch_size` into the memory, then read the data from the memory with `__getitem__`, and finally replace the data in the memory after each iteration. But I still don’t know how to achieve it. I have tried my idea as in the code above. I don't konw how to allocate the `load_data` function parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It look like you are trying to use torch `Dataset` in the wrong way. **Your `Dataset` subclass should neither batch the data itself nor use the number of workers.**

Batching the data and loading it in parallel is the role of the `DataLoader` class. You `Dataset` subclass `__getitem__` method should only returns 1 sample (and additionally one ground truth annotation) from the dataset, it should be data like `Tensor` or `Array` which can be concatenated in order to create a batch.

Take a look at the `Dataset` and `DataLoader` documentation that is pretty clear on this.

---

The purpose of `DataLoader` is to load (i.e. read from disk to memory) and pre-process your data in parallel. If you specified 8 workers, it roughly means that 8 parallel threads are calling the `__getitem__` method to create a batch of items. Note that `DataLoader` already "caches" the data and load them in advance to be ready in time (take a look at the `prefetch_factor` parameter).

This should be a sufficient compromise between loading speed and memory consumption, you should try this before writing any custom caching, loading and parallel processing of your data.

Comment: Hi, if getitem should only return 1 sample, How can I load the batch-size sample to the memory instead of disk nor the whole-size dataset to memory? How to implement this?

Comment: I edited my answer with detail about your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How to set the best num-workers to accelerate the dataloader

Comment: It depends on how many CPU cores you have, generally 4 or 8 will be good.